# Error using package name as "proto.messages.v1" in .proto with prost, and tonic in rust

Tags: rust, grpc, rust-tonic, prost, tonic-build

I'm new to Rust and trying to create a simple gRPC application. Here is the directory structure:

```
grpc-protobuf
├── Cargo.toml
├── build.rs
├── proto
│   ├── hello
│   │   └── hello.proto
│   └── messages
│       └── hello.proto
└── src
    └── lib.rs
```

I have the protobuf messages defined under *proto/messages/hello.proto* and below is the file content:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package proto.messages.v1;

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloResponse {
  string message = 1;
}
```

The service that uses the messages is defined as *proto/hello/hello.proto*:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package hello;

import "messages/hello.proto";

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (proto.messages.v1.HelloRequest) returns (proto.messages.v1.HelloResponse) {}
}
```

And here is how I'm creating a package:

```rust
pub mod hello {
    tonic::include_proto!("hello");
}

pub mod messages {
    tonic::include_proto!("proto.messages.v1");
}
```

As I try to build the package I get the following errors:

```bash
➜ cargo build -p grpc-protobuf
   Compiling grpc-protobuf v0.1.0 (/Users/gaurav.gahlot/workspace/rusty/rust-grpc/grpc-protobuf)
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `proto` in the crate root
  --> /Users/gaurav.gahlot/workspace/rusty/rust-grpc/target/debug/build/grpc-protobuf-6fc85551b5cb3a84/out/hello.rs:91:31
   |
91 |                 super::super::proto::messages::v1::HelloRequest,
   |                               ^^^^^ could not find `proto` in the crate root

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `proto` in the crate root
  --> /Users/gaurav.gahlot/workspace/rusty/rust-grpc/target/debug/build/grpc-protobuf-6fc85551b5cb3a84/out/hello.rs:94:43
   |
94 |             tonic::Response<super::super::proto::messages::v1::HelloResponse>,
   |                                           ^^^^^ could not find `proto` in the crate root

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `proto` in the crate root
   --> /Users/gaurav.gahlot/workspace/rusty/rust-grpc/target/debug/build/grpc-protobuf-6fc85551b5cb3a84/out/hello.rs:124:51
    |
```

Comment: Drive-by comment: proto `package` hierarchy is challenging but consistent. There are 2 components: the file system (root) path (I'd recommend you consider using `${PWD}/proto`) and the `package` path (which is relative to the root path). In this case, you have one package `package messages` (not `proto` because that's the root; and not `v1` because there's no folder `v1`) and `package hello` (as you have it). This would be a correct input structure for protoc.

Comment: It should then be `rpc SayHello(messages.HelloRequest) return (messages.HelloResponse)`

Comment: I'm going to repro your code as I'll find that the easiest way to debug it.

Comment: I'd encourage you to rename `messages/hello.proto` to `messages/messages.proto` too.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thank you for looking into it. I already tried using `package messages` instead of `package proto.messages.v1` and it worked with the lib setup as well. Considering your idea I have put the complete code at [gauravgahlot/rust-grpc](https://github.com/gauravgahlot/rust-grpc) GitHub repo. The `main` branch as the working code. The PR on the other hand has the versioning model I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Your PR is fine except you want `tonic::include_proto!("messages.v1");`. This is where it's a good idea to verify what `protoc` generated by looking at the `OUT_DIR` content.

Comment: `protoc` generated `messages.hello.v1.rs` and that's what I have in the PR as well. However, the build fails with the error:

`tonic::Response<super::super::messages::hello::v1::HelloResponse>,
                                                                      ^^^^^ could not find "hello" in "messages"`

You may check the build error [here](https://github.com/gauravgahlot/rust-grpc/actions/runs/5501362643/jobs/10024892525?pr=1).

Comment: You're not correctly referencing the `Hello*` Messages in the new package hierarchy. It is now `messages.hello.v1` (not just `messages`). So you need e.g. `messages::hello::v1::{HelloResponse, HelloRequest}` and `pub mod messages { pub mod hello { pub mod v1 {  tonic::include_proto!("messages.hello.v1"); }}}`

Comment: Aha! That's what I was missing. Thank you so much for your help. Please update your answer accordingly, and I would happy be to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replicated your file structure (I'm using `bin` rather than `lib`):

```
.
├── build.rs
├── Cargo.toml
├── proto
│   ├── hello
│   └── messages
├── src
│   └── main.rs
└── target
```

`proto/hello/hello.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package hello;

import "messages/messages.proto";

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (messages.HelloRequest) returns (messages.HelloResponse) {}
}
```

`proto/messages/messages.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package messages;

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloResponse {
  string message = 1;
}
```

`build.rs`:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    tonic_build::configure()
        .build_server(true)
        .compile(
            &[
                "proto/hello/hello.proto",
                "proto/messages/messages.proto",
            ],
            &["proto"],
        )?;
    Ok(())
}
```

> **NOTE** `tonic-build` permits crate relative addresses. The `proto_path` is defined to be `proto` and then individual protobuf files must include one of the `proto_path`'s (we only have `proto`) and the `package` path.

`main.rs`:

```rust
pub mod hello {
    tonic::include_proto!("hello");
}
pub mod messages {
    tonic::include_proto!("messages");
}

use hello::{
    greeter_server::{Greeter, GreeterServer},
};
use messages::{
    HelloRequest, HelloResponse,
};
```

Coming from using gRPC mostly with Go and some Python, I like how `tonic` works but found the `protoc` generation initially confusing. `tonic-build` uses `OUT_DIR` as the location for the `protoc` generated sources. You can:

```bash
ls target/debug/build/grpc-protobuf*/out
```

Yielding:

```
target/debug/build/grpc-protobuf-be913437690683ab/out:
hello.rs  messages.rs
```

###### Update

When you have a nested `package` hierarchy, e.g. `package messages.v1`, there are several changes in particular to the rust `mod` hierarchy to reflect the `package` hierarchy:

```
.
├── build.rs
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── proto
│   ├── hello
│   │   └── hello.proto
│   └── messages
│       └── v1
│           └── messages.proto
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── main.rs
└── target
```

> **NOTE** folder structure `proto/messages/v1` to reflect revised `package` name.

`proto/hello/hello.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package hello;

import "messages/v1/messages.proto";

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (messages.v1.HelloRequest)
    returns (messages.v1.HelloResponse) {}
}
```

> **NOTE** `messages.v1.Hello*`

`proto/messages/v1/messages.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package messages.v1;

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloResponse {
  string message = 1;
}
```

> **NOTE** `package` path updated.

`build.rs`:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    tonic_build::configure()
        .build_server(true)
        .compile(
            &[
                "proto/hello/hello.proto",
                "proto/messages/v1/messages.proto",
            ],
            &["proto"],
        )?;

    Ok(())
}
```

> **NOTE** proto imports updated.

`main.rs`:

```rust
pub mod hello {
    tonic::include_proto!("hello");
}
pub mod messages {
    pub mod v1 {
        tonic::include_proto!("messages.v1");
    }
}

use hello::{
    greeter_server::{Greeter,GreeterServer},
};
use messages::v1::{
    HelloRequest, HelloResponse,
};
```

> **NOTE** `pub mod messages { pub mod v1 { ... }}` and `use` updated.